# "I wish" subjunctives

Tags: subjunctives

I looked up a good many of answers about subjunctives. But still, it's not clear in my head. I've made up some sentences for it. Could you please review and correct them?

---

< Wishes for the future >

> I wish he would be here.

This means "I'm sorry that he won't come."

> I wish he could be here.

This means "I'm sorry that he won't manage to come."

---

< Wishes for the present >

> I wish he be here.

This means "I insist he should be here". It sounds formal.

> I wish he were here.

This means "I'm sorry that he is not here."

> I wish he was here.

This means the same with above one yet more informal.

---

< Wishes for the past >

> I wish he would have been here.

(Not used.)

> I wish he could have been here.

This means "I'm sorry that he couldn't come."

> I wish he had been here.

This means "I'm sorry that he didn't come."

---

< For the past wishes >

> I wished + (above all, except 'be')

This means "I was sorry that (above all)"

Ex) I wished he were here. = I was sorry that he wasn't here.

> I wished he be here.

This means "I insisted that he should be here."

---

How close am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly close.

> I wish he would be here

Not really idiomatic.  It's similar to the expression, *"I wish he would **get** here"* which implies he is *expected* but running late.

> I wish he could be here.

This implies lack of *ability*, not lack of *intention* -- although it can be used diplomatically to *imply* inability, when the cause is really lack of interest.

> I wish he be here

As you say, a formal and uncommon imperative, usually expressed with something stronger than "wish", *"I **require** he be here for his sister's wedding"*.  Alternately it may be common in "Pirate" dialect which substitutes "be" for most conjugations of the "to be" verb. *"Arr matey who be ye?"* (= "Hey, who are you?")

> I wish he would have been here.

This is fine.  It suggests he was unable to be here *for unspecified reasons*, although his attendance was desired. *"I wish he would have been there when our father died."*

---

It might be more useful to make up some sample sentences and see if they mean what you think they mean.  For example:

> I wish he would have been here when the storm hit.
>
> I wished he could have been here for the party.

And so on.